# How to compare the count of command line arguments correctly in NASM?

Tags: linux, nasm, x86-64

I am learning x86_64 NASM assembly on Ubuntu 16.10 on Docker for Mac.

The following program takes two command line arguments, and sum these.
If number of command line arguments is not two, print error message (jump to `argcError`).

When I exec this program, it jump to argcError section despite passed to two command line arguments.

Why this program jump to `argError`?

```
section .data
    SYS_WRITE equ 1
    STD_IN equ 1
    SYS_EXIT equ 60
    EXIT_CODE equ 0

    NEW_LINE db 0xa
    WRONG_ARGC db "Must be two command line arguments", 0xa

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    pop rcx
    cmp rcx, 3
    jne argcError
    add rsp, 8
    pop rsi
    call str_to_int

    mov r10, rax
    pop rsi
    call str_to_int
    mov r11, rax
    add r10, r11




argcError:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, WRONG_ARGC
    mov rdx, 35
    syscall
    jmp exit


str_to_int:
    xor rax, rax
    mov rcx, 10
next:
    cmp [rsi], byte 0
    je return_str
    mov bl, [rsi]
    sub bl, 48
    mul rcx ; rax = rax * rcx
    add rax, rbx
    inc rsi
    jmp next

return_str:
    ret

int_to_str:
    mov rdx, 0
    mov rbx, 10
    div rbx
    add rdx, 48
    add rdx, 0x0
    push rdx
    inc r12
    cmp rax, 0x0
    jne int_to_str
    jmp print


print:
    ; calculate byte length of number string
    mov rax, 1
    mul r12
    mov r12, 8
    mul r12
    mov rdx, rax
    ; print sum
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov rdi, STD_IN
    mov rsi, rsp
    syscall

    jmp printNewline

printNewline:
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov rdi, STD_IN
    mov rsi, NEW_LINE
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
    jmp exit

exit:
    mov rax, SYS_EXIT
    mov rdi, EXIT_CODE
    syscall
```

Comment: the code in `_start` you have `call str_to_int
    mov r11, rax
    add r10, r11` and then you continue by executing the code in argcError. I think you want to jump to the exit label after `add r10, r11` . Have you tried stepping through this with a debugger like GDB?

Answer (score 0):

There probably other errors in your code as pointed out by Micheal Petch, but the way you've initialized RSI is incorrect. Yes, ESP does point to the number of arguments passed, but popping it off the stack and then adding 8 to ESP again is functionally equivalent too.

```
mov     rcx, [rsp]
```

Then by popping into RSI it only becomes a copy of RCX. If you want to do that it should look like this

```
pop     rcx
.......
add     rsp, 24               ; Now RSP is pointing to proper place in array of pointers
pop     rsi
add     rsp, 16               ; Now point to pointer to second argument
pop     rsi
```

An alternative would be this next example only because my personal preference is not to use stack pointer for other than that which it was intended.

```
mov     rsi, rsp
lodsq                          ; Read # of arguments passed by OS
add     rsi, 8                 ; bounce over application name
cmp      al, 3
jnz     argError
push    rsi
lodsq
mov     rsi, rax               ; RSI points to first agument
call    Convert
pop     rsi
lodsq
mov     rsi, rax
call    Convert
```